# Why can we call .orElse() on Optional.of()?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I'm curious why is it possible to do this (at least on Java 8):

```
Optional.of(null).orElse("something");
```

`Optional.of(null)` is basically a guaranteed null pointer. Making possible to invoke `.orElse()` on it gives a clumsy developer unexpected holes to fall into. I've been looking around to see if there's any justification to this. Maybe there's some scenario that this is supposed to address?

Comment: `javac` has no compiler support for checking _if_ you pass a null, this is not very different than to _any_ other method  call.

Comment: @Eugene I'd say that the problem is more that `javac` has no sense of the *semantics* of `Optional` so it doesn't know what that line means in practice.

Comment: `orElse` is like any method, it is based on the type of the variable, not the instance itself. So here, you have an `Optional`, that's all. The exception that will occurs is a runtime exception so it may or may not happen, that's not on the compiler hand, it is in yours

Comment: You may like Kotlin if you don't like null pointer issues. It is much like Java but it avoids some pitfalls.

Comment: Why do you focus on the ability to invoke `.orElse()` when the actual error is the expression `Optional.of(null)` which will fail at runtime? Why do you think, allowing `Optional.of(null)` without `.orElse()` would be better?

Comment: I agree that this is a reasonable question. There are IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA which will warn you about all sorts of probable-mistakes like this based on semantically-aware static checking. It would be possible for `javac` to do the same checks in principle, and it's reasonable to ask why it doesn't.

Comment: @kaya3 because `javac` is not an IDE.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I didn't ask any "why" question, or any question at all. I am well aware that `javac` is not an IDE, and nothing I wrote suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this for the same reason you can write `((String) null).length()`. The Java compiler has a static checker for certain things like type-safety, but does not check for or reject code which provably throws a `NullPointerException`. If it did, the code `throw new NullPointerException();` would not be allowed either.

It's not generally the case that code which throws an exception is a mistake. While a static checker could detect this kind of thing and warn about it, it would be bad if this was an error. Some IDEs will generate their own warnings about probable-mistakes, but you have to decide what is or isn't worth checking for.

Detecting this probable-mistake requires a static checker designed with knowledge of the behaviour of the `Optional.of` method. The authors of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/) have made the decision to warn for things like unsafe casts, but not for anything which depends on the semantics of the methods being used. One advantage of this decision is that it means the JLS can be maintained separately from the [Java Class Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library) documentation.

Answer (score 7):

There are languages where there is support for null checking right into the compiler (or even better languages that don't have such a "thing" at all) - this is burned into the compiler.

`javac` is not a such compiler and the be frank - I don't want it to become like this either. There are languages where there is syntax like `!` or `?` or `!?` - when I read this code it either screams on me or asks me something (this is my opinion).

Now, recall that `Optional` is designed for return types, so inside your method body you use an `Optional` chain of methods. If you *really* want to check if something is null or not there is `Objects::requireNonNull` - use that; if you are unsure if something is null or not, you could use `Optional::ofNullable`.

I know and read the arguments for `Optional::of` *and* `Optional::ofNullable`, I still don't like it, I wish it could be just the latter. But hey, people don't have to agree all the time: we do have `Optional::isEmpty` **and** `Optional::isPresent`. Is that a good decision? I don't know.

Like any other method call, you can pass `null` to *any* object reference, `Optional` is no different. Could they add semantics for the `javac` to support only `Optional::of` and null checking? Probably. How many people would request such a support for *and this feature please*?

Comment: Regarding `Optional::isEmpty` and `Optional::isPresent`, I think it is a good design choice to have both. `isEmpty` is a standard method for container types, and `isPresent` is useful to be passed as a method reference to `Stream.filter`, so you don't have to write `.filter(o -> !o.isEmpty())` as a lambda function every time.

Comment: @kaya3 Sometimes I wish `Stream` had some sort of "`exclude(Predicate)`" convenience method—it could simply delegate to `filter(predicate.negate())`. Though your argument obviously doesn't just apply to `Stream`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Optional.of(null).orElse();
```

Obviously the above code will always cause an exception. But what about:

```
Optional.of(someMethod()).orElse();
```

with

```
Object someMethod() { return null; }
```

You probably think: sure, same thing.

Well, actually that is wrong. What if a **subclass** overrides `someMethod()` to return a value other than `null`?! Thus you can't decide at *compile* time whether that method will *always* return null at *runtime*.

Long story short: there are **plenty** of obvious, and also less obvious situations where the compiler *could* apply all kinds of techniques, like data flow analysis to determine whether code **will** result in a runtime exception or not. But there are also many others where that isn't possible.

The point here: it is up to the people defining the language to determine what they expect compilers to care about.

The java people opted for a **simple** compiler. One that compiles fast, and that isn't overly complicated to implement. Why? Because the compiler simply avoid overly complicated checking.